# PHP Download File with Include

Tags: php, file, download, include

How can I use PHP's include function to include a file and then modify the headers so it forces - at least that's how it's called - browsers to download ITSELF (the PHP file). Is it possible to also modify the preset save name, in order to change the extension from *.php to something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which PHP file do you mean exactly? The including file or the included one?

Comment: The including. That's why I include a file. So one doesn't know the path of the included file and only downloads the including one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP [include](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function will parse the file. What you want to do is use [file_get_contents](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [readfile](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Here's an example from the readfile documentation:

```
$file = 'somefile.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Change the headers to suit your particular needs. Check out the above links for more info.

Comment: OK. Thanks for that one! But how can I then download the file, anyway? Or even force the download?

Comment: with: echo file_get_contents('source_of_file');

Comment: How can I use file_get_contents with subfolders? It just won't work :(

Comment: Try using an absolute path. For more flexibility, you can prepend a relative path with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].